# Is there an inverse function for $h=(-6y+100)\sin(\arctan(y/100))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$h=(-6y+100)\sin\left(\arctan(\frac{y}{100})\right)$$

I need the inverse function: $y= \;?\;$

I'm not a mathematician so any help would be great.

Comment: Could you show us what work you've done, or what thoughts you have? you should edit your question to show this.

Comment: Is this homework or assignment ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Notice that $$\sin (\arctan u)={u\over\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$Can you finish now?

Answer (score 1):

Let us rewrite the equation$$h=(-6y+100)\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{100}\right)\right)$$ as
$$k=(1-{6z} )\sin\left(\arctan\left(z\right)\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\frac h {100}\qquad \text{and} \qquad z=\frac y {100}$$
Taking into account what @Mostafa Ayaz already wrote, we end with 
$$k=\frac{z \,(1-6 z)}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}\tag 1$$ Squaring and rearranging, we end with the quartic polynomial
$$36 z^4-12 z^3+\left(1-k^2\right) z^2-k^2=0$$ which can be [solved with radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function).

The solutions can be **exactly** obtained using the method described in the linked Wikipedia page, we have
$$\Delta=-576 k^4 \left(k^6+285 k^4+21459 k^2-37\right)\qquad P=-288 k^2-144 \qquad Q=-1728 k^2$$
$$\Delta_0=k^4-434 k^2+1\qquad D=-20736 k^2 \left(k^2+146\right)$$ For $k>0.0415232$, $\Delta <0$  and then the equation has two distinct real roots and two complex conjugate non-real roots. In any manner, the solutions will be quite ugly.

However, assuming $z >0$, we can make a quite good approximation using a $[2,2]$ Padé approximant built at $z=0$ and get
$$k\approx \frac{2 (1-6 z) z}{z^2+2}$$ which reduces the problem to a quadratic polynomial in $z$ showing as roots
$$z_\pm=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-2 k^2-24 k+1}}{k+12}\tag 2$$
If you are ready for a cubic, a better approximation would be
$$k\approx \frac{z(292 -10511 z^2)}{(6 z+1) \left(147 z^2+292\right)}$$ but its solutions will still be ugly.

To check the "quality" of $(2)$, let us give a value to $z$; with it, compute the exact value of $k$ from $(1)$ and use $(2)$ to recompute $z$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
z_{given} & k & z_- \\
 0.00 & 0.0000000 & 0.0000000 \\
 0.01 & 0.0093995 & 0.0100000 \\
 0.02 & 0.0175965 & 0.0200000 \\
 0.03 & 0.0245889 & 0.0300000 \\
 0.04 & 0.0303757 & 0.0400000 \\
 0.05 & 0.0349563 & 0.0500001 \\
 0.06 & 0.0383311 & 0.0600002 \\
 0.07 & 0.0405009 & 0.0700008 \\
 0.08 & 0.0414675 & 0.0800058
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

With respect to your comment, consider the function
$$f(z)=\frac{z \,(1-6 z)}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}-k$$ Its derivative $$f'(z)=\frac{1-6 z \left(z^2+2\right)}{\left(z^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$ cancels when $$6 z^3+12 z-1=0$$ This cubic equation has only one real root given by 
$$z_*=\frac{\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{393}}}{6^{2/3}}-\frac{2\ 2^{2/3}}{\sqrt[3]{3
   \left(3+\sqrt{393}\right)}}\approx 0.083047$$ The second derivative test would show that this is a maximum. At this point
$$f(z_*)\approx 0.0415232-k$$ I hope that you understand that this explains your problem.

Comment: Thank you Claude and @Mostafa Ayaz. As I said I'm not a mathematician so I needed some time before it made any sense to me. Mostafa's post was helpful but I'm missing the basic skills to finish it. I tried Claude's solution which workes fine. As you said, not precise but for me it is accurate enough. That said, I notice that for z-given 0.09 I get no results because of a SQRT of a negative number? Is there a way around that? Thanks again! Paul

Comment: @pstr. See my edit.